# Search and replace one-liner preserve newline characters

Tags: regex, perl

sample_file:

```
this is a test line!
this is a test line!
this is a test line!
this is a test line!
```

I'm using a Perl one-liner to replace text like this:

```
perl -pi -e 's{this(.*)\s}{\n\1\n}i && s{.*\n}{}' sample_file
```

The `this(.*)\s` part and `\1` part are variable and I cannot change that (it comes from user input).

My problem is that I need to adjust the `{\n\1\n}` part depending on whether the first regex includes the newline character .

For example, if the first regex is `{this(.*)\s}` I need `{\n\1\n}`, but if the first is like `{(.*)a test}` I need `{\n\1}`.

How can I check whether the newline character is lost and put it back if necessary?

Comment: It won't work in the first place - `-pi` will cause your thing to iterate line by line anyway.

Comment: You are starting from the wrong place and your question is misleading. I suggest that you ask another question, showing what you have tried, and describe the transformation that you want to apply to your file.

Comment: You really shouldn't be asking your users to enter regex patterns!

Comment: The users are specialists with regex, but that is not the point. I don't see how the question is misleading, but I can see you judge it as poorly formulated. It's kind of difficult to explain, since the text files vary and so do the regexes. The users enter regexes to transform each line to a line that they want. Sometimes a regex looks like the one in the question. I have this perl "template" `perl -pi -e 's{[regex]}{\n[output]}i && s{.*\n}{}' sample_file` which works, except in the example I give in the question, then there needs to be an extra \n after [output]. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Please put your clarification into your question. It may be "difficult to explain" but it's ***impossible*** to program *until* you have explained it. *"specialists with regex"* are extremely rare, and I hope that you chose your words carefully. Your implementation sounds disastrous, even if we ignore malicious input. Assuming you have so many specialists, why don't you get one of them to fix your problem?

Comment: *I have this perl "template" ... which works, except in the example I give in the question*. Yes, until the next case where it won't work. And then the third case that's found. There is no way that this should be a one-liner; I would quote two weeks and 500 lines of Perl to implement what you're trying to do, and a month of testing before letting it close to live data. You are allowing your users to write *Perl code* (like `unlink <*>`) that your system executes without verification. Although that is foolish, I am certain that you will go ahead and implement it. May God keep you safe.

Comment: If we were to remove the silly "one liner" requirement, and the requirement that users be allowed to pass regular expressions as input, perhaps you could explain the actual objective -- as in, what is it that your users need to accomplish when calling your script?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want to `chomp` inputs lines, and add a newline to output lines. `-l` (in conjunction with `-n` or `-p`) will do both.

For example, the following doesn't replace the newline with `!` because it was removed by `-l` (and subsequently re-added by the `print`).

```
perl -i -ple's/\s/!/g' file
```

---

By the way, `\1` ("match what the first capture captured") makes no sense in a substitution. You want `$1` (as `-w` would tell you).